# Method getElementById() returns null

Tags: java, dom

I set id attribute the following way:

```
Element node = document.createElement("something");
node.setAttribute("id", "1");
node.setIdAttribute("id", true);
```

Then I check if this is really id attribute:

```
node.getAttributeNode("id").isId());
```

returns true

But when I try to get the node by its id

```
document.getElementById("1");
```

or even

```
document.getElementById(node.getAttributeNode("id").getValue())
```

I get null

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This looks like it is Javascript, not Java.  Also, you are doing `document.getElementById("id")` where it should be:  `document.getElementById("1")` because you set the ID to 1.  As a key point though, I feel setting an ID to a stringified number isnt the best practice.  It should be something more understandable / readable.

Comment: Sorry, that was my typo, of course there must be "1", fixed.

Comment: So, does the error still persist?  Can you create a JS Fiddle with the Code you have so we can debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that you put the wrong tag, it looks like you defined the ID of your element to be "1" So that means to reference it, you should also reference it by "1"

```
document.getElementById("1");
```

would return you the DOM object in your markup, so long as it exists in the markup. Depending on the frameworks, it might be pulled from the Dom, but that is not always the case for beginner programming.

As a note for you, a ID should be unique, but at the same time it is good to name it something human readable.  The reason for it is that you will come back to this code later and have absolutely no clue what it does.

If you name things accordingly, it will make it easier on you, also allowing you to create and follow the best practices for programming in general.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that in the previous answers.
The problem with your code is that the created node

```
var node = document.createElement("sector");
node.setAttribute("id", "1");
```

is not in the document yet. You must add it.
Example

```
// Adding the node to the body.
document.body.append(node)
```

and now

```
document.getElementById(1)
```

Comment: This is Java, not JS. I've tried to use 
document.appendChild(node);
but got an exception:
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted.

Comment: You must append the node in the 'body', 'head' o a previusly existing element

Comment: @KonstantinM - Try `document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(node);`